# Quadratic using the roots of unity, where $\omega^7 = 1, \omega \neq 1$

Tags: complex-numbers, quadratics, roots-of-unity

Say that $\omega$ is a complex number, where $\omega^7 = 1, \omega \neq 1$.

Let $\alpha = \omega + \omega^2 + \omega^4$ and $\beta = \omega^3 + \omega^5 + \omega^6$. $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are roots of the quadratic
$x^2 + px + q = 0$, given
for some integers $p$ and $q$. What is the ordered pair $(p,q)$?

The roots of unity is tricky for me, so hints to get me started would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:** $$1+\omega+\cdots+\omega^6 = 0, \qquad \alpha + \beta = -p, \quad \alpha\beta = q.$$

Comment: Direct computations of $\alpha+\beta$ and $\alpha \beta$ using that the sum of the powers above is zero really yields the values for $p$ and $q$. Go for it!

Comment: Does $p=1$? For $q$, after multiplying $\alpha*\beta$, I found that the resulting polynomial was $\omega^4+\omega^5+\omega^6+3 \omega^7+\omega^8+\omega^9+\omega^{10}$. How would you suggest I apply the formula that you provided which stated that the sum of the powers is zero to this polynomial?

Comment: It seems that $p = 1$. Trust yourself more. To get rid of these higher powers, notice that if $k > 0$, then $\omega^{7+k} = \omega^7\omega^k = \omega^k$. If you are comfortable with modular arithmetic, you can always write $\omega^n = \omega^k$, with $0 \leq k < 7$ and $n \equiv k \pmod 7$. For example, $\omega^9 = \omega^2$.

Comment: Using modular arithmetic, the polynomial is reduced to: $\omega+\omega^2+\omega^3+\omega^4+\omega^5+\omega^6+3\omega^7$.

Comment: You are forgetting that $\omega^7 = 1$.

Comment: Ah. If I calculated it correctly, then $q=2$, so $(p,q) = (1,2)$?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that $p$ is the negative sum of the roots and $q$ is their product. The roots are equally spaced on the unit circle starting with $\omega^0=1$